# regex literal pattern match with multiple words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Trying to match the literal word 
NEGATIVE (just by itself)

but my regex is also matching on these:

NEGATIVE

NEGATIVE DILUTE

How do I not have it not match at all when the phrase is NEGATIVE DILUTE or any other phrase besides just NEGATIVE

This is in jQuery and my regex so far is this:

```
    /\bNEGATIVE\b/i
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"This is in jQuery"_ - You might be using jQuery, but the [regex functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is provided by JavaScript itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^NEGATIVE$
```

This will match `NEGATIVE`, and will not match if there is anything before or after it. Basically, if the string only contains the phrase and nothing else.

Here's a site that will explain this regex and any others you input: http://www.regex101.com/r/iA7fY5

Comment: Very helpful, and the explanation site is great too.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ to indicate that the regex should start at the beginning of the string and $ to indicate the end of the match must equal the end of the string:

```
^NEGATIVE$
```